# How to properly delete file related to record

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to delete icon file related to current news if news was deleted.
I see 2 approaches.

First:

```
public function admin_delete ($id = null, $icon = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    if ($this->News->delete($id)) {
        unlink(WWW_ROOT . 'img/icons/news/' . $icon);
        $this->Session->setFlash('ok!');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

I need to pass the record ID and filename to this action from view.
For me it seems slightly ugly and also can cause Nginx related issues.

Second one:

```
public function admin_delete ($id = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }
    $icon = $this->News->read('icon', $id);
    if ($this->News->delete($id)) {
        unlink(WWW_ROOT . 'img/icons/news/' . $icon['icon']);
        $this->Session->setFlash('ok!');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure is it a good approach and should I use `read` or `find('first')`.
I hope you can give me some advice on how to do it in more correct way. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of that stuff should be in controller. Fetch the record using `find('first')` in the model's `beforeDelete()` and save the filename in a model property. Then in `afterDelete()` delete file who's filename you cached in `beforeDelete()`.